# Rewriting the max/min of several random variables to plot each case to understand the problem visually.

Tags: probability, random-variables

For two random variables $X$ and $Y$, considering $W=\max (X,Y)$ or $W=\min (X,Y)$, I have learnt to rewrite $W$ in following way 
$$W=\max(X,Y)=\begin{cases} X & \textrm{ if } X\geq Y \\ Y & \textrm{ if } X<Y  \end{cases}.\bigg\}\to (1)\\ W=\min(X,Y)=\begin{cases} Y & \textrm{ if } X\geq Y \\ X & \textrm{ if } X<Y  \end{cases}.\bigg\} \to (2)$$.

I can find out the distribution function $F_W(w)$ for $W=\max(X,Y)$ or $W=\min(X,Y)$.

Now, specifically, I want to learn how to rewrite $\max (X,Y,Z), \min (X,Y,Z), \max(X, \min(Y,Z)), \min(Z, \max(X,Y))$. So that I can plot the graph of each cases (such as $X\geq Y\geq Z$, $X<Y<Z$.. etc) to understand the problems visually and to find out the distribution function $F_W(w)=P(W\leq w)$ at each case, considering $$(i).\ W=\max (X,Y,Z),\\(ii) \ W=\min(X,Y,Z), \\(iii) \ W= \max(X, \min(Y,Z))\\ (iv) \ W= \min(Z, \max(X,Y))$$

. But how to rewrite $W$ for three random variables $X$, $Y$, $Z$, where it is given that

$W=\max(X,Y,Z)$.

Here is my first approach (don't know if it is correct or not) to rewrite $(i)$ ..

$$W=\max(X,Y,Z)=\begin{cases} X & \textrm{ if } X\geq Y\geq Z\\X & \textrm{ if } X\geq Z\geq Y \\ \max(X,Z)=Z & \textrm{ if } X\geq Y\leq Z\\\max(X,Y)=Y & \textrm{ if } X\geq Z\leq Y \\\min(X,Z)=X & \textrm{ if } X< Y> Z \\\min(X,Y)=X & \textrm{ if } X< Z> Y \\Y & \textrm{ if } Y\geq Z\geq X \\Y & \textrm{ if } Y\geq X\geq Z \\\max(Y,Z)=Z & \textrm{ if } Y\geq X\leq Z\\\max(X,Y)=X & \textrm{ if } Y\geq Z\leq X \\\min(Y,Z)=Y & \textrm{ if } Y< X> Z\\\min(X,Y)=Y & \textrm{ if } Y< Z> X \\ Z & \textrm{ if } Z\geq X\geq Y \\ Z & \textrm{ if } Z\geq Y\geq X\\ \max(X,Z)=X & \textrm{ if } Z\geq Y\leq X \\ \max(Y,Z)=Y & \textrm{ if } Z\geq X\leq Y \\ \min(Y,Z)=Z & \textrm{ if } Z< X> Y \\ \min(X,Z)=Z & \textrm{ if } Z< Y> X \end{cases}.$$

And a second approach to rewrite $W=\max(X,Y,Z)$.

Define events $$(X\geq Y) \textrm{ as } \mathbb {A}\ \textrm{&} \space (X<Y) \textrm{ as } \mathbb {A'}\\ (Y\geq Z) \textrm{ as } \mathbb {B}\ \textrm{&} \space (Y<Z) \textrm{ as } \mathbb {B'}\\ (Z\geq X) \textrm{ as } \mathbb {C}\ \textrm{&} \space (Z<X) \textrm{ as } \mathbb {C'}$$

$\therefore$ $$W=\max(X,Y,Z)=\begin{cases} X & \textrm{ if } \mathbb {A} \cup  \mathbb{B}\\Y & \textrm{ if } \mathbb {B} \cup  \mathbb{C}\\Z & \textrm{ if } \mathbb {C} \cup  \mathbb{A}\\ Z & \textrm{ if } \mathbb {A} \cup  \mathbb{B'}\\ X & \textrm{ if } \mathbb {A} \cup  \mathbb{C'}\\ Y & \textrm{ if } \mathbb {B} \cup  \mathbb{A'}\\X & \textrm{ if } \mathbb {B} \cup  \mathbb{C'}\\Y & \textrm{ if } \mathbb {C} \cup  \mathbb{A'}\\Z & \textrm{ if } \mathbb {C} \cup  \mathbb{B'}\\Z & \textrm{ if } \mathbb {A'} \cup  \mathbb{B'} \\X & \textrm{ if } \mathbb {B'} \cup  \mathbb{C'}\\Y & \textrm{ if } \mathbb {C'} \cup  \mathbb{A'}  \end{cases}.$$

Due to little knowledge I am confused and stuck to rewrite $(iii)$ and $(iv)$. If rewriting $(i)$ is correct, then $(ii)$ can be defined as the reverse of $(i)$.

Any help or explanation is valuable for learning and highly appreciated.

Comment: You have 3 variables, so there should be only $3! = 6$ ways to order them, just as in the 2 variables case you have only $2! = 2$ ways to order them.  E.g. $\max(X, \min(Y,Z)) = Y$ in the case of this ordering: $Z \ge Y \ge X$ (one of 6 possible).

Comment: @antkam, thank you for this reply. But I am sure about $3$ outcomes from $$W=\max(X,Y,Z)= X , \ if \space X\geq Y\geq Z \\ Y, \ if \space Y\geq X\geq Z \\ Z, \ if \space  Z\geq Y\geq X$$. 

Actually I am not sure except these $3$ which other $3$ cases are correct from $(i)$. Also would you explain how $\max(X, \min(Y,Z)) = Y$ .?

Comment: If $Z \ge Y \ge X$, then $\min(Y,Z) = Y$ and so $\max(X, \min(Y,Z)) = \max(X, Y) = Y$.  Also, in your case, $\max(X,Y,Z) = X$ if either $X\ge Y \ge Z$ or $X \ge Z \ge Y$ (those being 2 out of 6 possible orderings).

Comment: @antkam, To be clear on this topic, is each interpretation correct in $(i)$? and what is the outcome when $X\geq Y\leq Z$ or $X<Y>Z$?.

Comment: $X \ge Y \le Z$ is **not** a complete ordering!  E.g. which is bigger, $X$ or $Z$?  You just need to list 6 cases, being the 6 possible complete orderings, and compute whether $W = X$ or $Y$ or $Z$ in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only six cases you need to consider, corresponding to total orderings of $(X,Y,Z)$; if there can be ties, then these cases are not mutually exclusive, but this doesn't matter for calculating maxes and mins.  Here is the table of outcomes:
\begin{array}{ c | c }
 \text{Case} & \max(X,Y,Z) & \min(X,Y,Z) & \max(X,\min(Y,Z)) & \min(Z,\max(X,Y))\\ \hline
 X \le Y \le Z & Z & X & Y & Y \\ \hline
 X \le Z \le Y & Y & X & Z & Z \\ \hline
 Y \le X \le Z & Z & Y & X & X \\ \hline
 Y \le Z \le X & X & Y & X & Z \\ \hline
 Z \le X \le Y & Y & Z & X & Z \\ \hline
 Z \le Y \le X & X & Z & X & Z     
\end{array}
Note that there are $3^6=729$ possible "columns" for this table.  It's an interesting exercise to think about whether you can write an expression corresponding to each.  Thus far you have $3$ for single variables, $6$ for the min or max of a pair, $2$ for the min or max of all three, and $6$ more for the min (max) of one variable with the max (min) of the other two... only $17$!

Comment: (+1) to your answer. I need to understand the part $6 \  \text {for the min or max of a pair}, \ 2 \text{ for the min or max of all three} \  \text{and} \ 6 \ \text {more for the min (max) of one variable with the max (min) of the other two}$ from your answer. would you like to explain it?

Comment: If you mean cases , then the line from your explanation " $6$ more for the min (max) of one variable with the max (min) of the other two" implies, 

$$\max(X, \min (Y,Z)), \max(Y, \min (X,Z)), \max(Z, \min (X,Y)), \min(X, \max (Y,Z)), \min(Y, \max (X,Z)), \min(Z, \max (X,Y))$$

and the line " $6$ for the min or max of a pair" implies

$$\max(X,Y), \max(Y,Z), \max(X,Z), \min(X,Y), \min(Y,Z), \min(X,Z)$$ 
 but cannot get the line that says " $3$ for the single variables "

Comment: Oh, I just mean you could have a whole column of $X$, of $Y$, or of $Z$.  Other possibilities include $\min(\max(X,Y), \max(X,Z))$, for instance.

Comment: I got it. Thank you sir.